# PHP Code not binding with img src Tag

Tags: php, html, image

I have Tried Many Solution , Inside and Outside PHP Code , None of them are working 
I am able to fetch Image Path from Array But Not able to assign it ..

I Tried following solutions :

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "Image Path is ".$item[0]["Image"] ; //--> Returning - img01.jpg

    $imageNumber= "img01";

    //sol 1.   
    echo '<img src="'.$item[0]["Image"]'">';

    //sol 2.   
    // echo "<img src=\"{$imageNumber}.jpg\">";

    //sol 3.
    //echo '<img src="'.$coverlink.'" alt="Cover">';
}

//sol 4.
// <img src="<?php echo $imageNumber ?>.jpg">

//sol 5.
// <img src="<?php echo $item[0]["Image"]; ?>">
```

I need some guidence what I am missing ?Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: $data is a json decoded array , $item[0]["Image"] giving "img01.JPG"

Comment: Perhaps it would be wise to post the raw data so others can see the structure?

Comment: When `$item[0]["Image"]` is `img01.JPG` then `$item[0]["Image"].'.jpg'` is `img01.JPG.jpg`?!

Comment: edited that. typo error

Comment: and why jquery is tagged in your post ?

Comment: Just to be sure of the problem; the issue is that the images doesn't display right? (If so, have you tried to open your console to see if it throws 404? - and if so, check the path of the images)

Comment: So `echo '<img src="'.$item[0]["Image"]'">';` is correct. What is the problem remaining? Are you sure the image is in the correct folder?

Comment: it giving error ...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''">'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I see it now, you are missing a `.` at your echo line, use `echo '<img src="'.$item[0]["Image"] . '">';`

Comment: yes , thats the answer . thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted, it seems like $item[0]["Image"] returns the image name along with the extension. E.g: img01.jpg.
So, you can simply put this within the img src.

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
   echo "<img src='".$item[0]["Image"]."' />";
}
```

If your question is explained clearly, then this should work just fine.